# Indicating that a question has been answered

Tags: discussion

Several times now, my questions have been answered "unofficially" in the comments section, rather than posted as an "official" answer.  In such a case, how can I, as the OP, indicate that my question has been resolved and give credit to whom credit is due?

Comment: you can suggest to the poster of the "acceptable" comment to post that as an answer.  (this has been asked before, but i'm not where i can easily check for duplicates.  i will post a partial or unchecked answer in a comment when i'm in a situation where i can't test what i'm suggesting.  i'd rather test than post a wrong answer; it's easier to delete a bogus comment.)

Comment: Regarding Barbara’s “has been asked before”: [What if a comment answers a question?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1731/). Also related: [Why do people answer in comments?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3238/)